# Approaches to sub categories of polymorphic associations in Rails

Tags: ruby, polymorphic-associations, unique-constraint

Hello Everyone,

I have a polymorphic association currently in use with a few different models. Each model has it's own video file associated with it, so it uses a "videoable" polymorphic association. I recently found the need however, to create a new model that has 2 separate types of videos. I will let the code do the talking.

```
#current setup
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :videoable, :polymorphic => true
end


class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :video, :as => videoable
end

# New model I am working on
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :video_draft
    has_one :video_final
end
```

Ideally the assignment model would have two special types of video objects while still using the polymorphic association. I have considered single table inheritance, but I am not sure that is the best approach here. What are my options? I do not want to create a video_draft model and a video_final model because in the end, they are just video attachments like everything else. The only difference is that they are specialized video attachments that need their own unique reference.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to tell `ActiveRecord` what model are you referring to when declaring `:video_draft` instead of `:video` like in `Project` model. This can be done by passing `:class_name` option to `has_one`

Keeping this in mind, this should work fine:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :video_draft, :as => :videoable, :class_name => "Video"
    has_one :video_final, :as => :videoable, :class_name => "Video"
end
```

See [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference) at section 4.2.2.3 for more info about need for passing `:class_name`.

Comment: That was actually my first approach. What actually ends up happening though, is that :video_draft and :video_final end up pointing to the same thing. The Video table has a "videoable_type" and a "videoable_id" which point to the ModelName and ModelID which has a video.

Comment: Just checked it doing the following:
http://pastebin.com/bVMq0AvN
here's the result in db for this:
http://pastebin.com/yKP6AV3q

As you can see two videos were created. I have no idea why would it end up in pointing to the same object. Perhaps you could run same commands in your ruby console and show the result here?

Comment: If you look at the videos database you provided, you should see that there is no differentiating factor between the two videos. There is nothing that says one is a draft and the other is the final version.

Comment: Ah, OK now I see what you mean. Why not adding boolean `draft` (default false) column to videos table? Then you could use the following on the Assignment model instance:
assignment.create_video_draft(:draft => true)

Comment: Also, you'd have to change has_one declaration in Assignment model.
I think to sth like the following:
`has_one :video_draft, :as => :videoable, :class_name => "Video", :conditions => "draft  = 1"`
This should resolve the problem when ActiveRecord doesn't know which record is video_draft and video_final.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, but after much deliberation I think I will go with Single Table Inheritance. That way I can throw in any logic related to drafts and final videos into their own model, but they will all still use the same table.